# Continued Group Header

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2013

MS Access 2013

When repeating a group header (not the Page or Report Header), is there a way to change what displays?

What I have: A report with one group, and in the header section of that group displays the group name.  Group Header "Repeat Section" property is set to "Yes", which displays the group header each time that group breaks to the next column and/or next page.  This all works fine.

What I'd like to do is:  For the first instance of the group header the group should be displayed (i.e. "Group 1").  For each instance after the first, I'd like to add a designation that it is continued (i.e. "Group 1 (cont.)").

Anyone have suggestions?
I don't mind adding in VBA if necessary.

Thanks, Paulie

Answer (score 0):

try something like:

```
Private m_isFirst As Boolean

Private Sub GroupHeader0_Format(Cancel As Integer, FormatCount As Integer)
    m_isFirst = False
    If m_isFirst Then
        label1 = "Header"
    Else
        label1 = "Header (cont...)"
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Report_Load()
    m_isFirst = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Good thought, and probably should have put this earlier.  The only control in the group header is a textbox that is bound to data, which is the grouping.